# Is there an Erlang behaviour that can act on its own instead of waiting to be called?

Tags: erlang, behavior, tail-recursion, erlang-otp

I'm writing an Erlang application that requires actively polling some remote resources, and I want the process that does the polling to fit into the OTP supervision trees and support all the standard facilities like proper termination, hot code reloading, etc.

However, the two default behaviours, `gen_server` and `gen_fsm` seem to only support operation based on callbacks. I could abuse `gen_server` to do that through calls to self or abuse `gen_fsm` by having a single state that always loops to itself with a timeout 0, but I'm not sure that's safe (i.e. doesn't exhaust the stack or accumulate unread messages in the mailbox).

I could make my process into a [special process](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html) and write all that handling myself, but that effectively makes me reimplement the Erlang equivalent of the wheel.

So is there a behavior for code like this?

```
loop(State) ->
  do_stuff(State), % without waiting to be called
  loop(NewState).
```

And if not, is there a safe way to trick default behaviours into doing this without exhausting the stack or accumulating messages over time or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of doing that in Erlang is by using `erlang:send_after/3`. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883741/how-to-perform-actions-periodically-with-erlangs-gen-server) and also this [example implementation](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/hbd_pool.erl#L66).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you could employ an essentially non OTP compliant process? Although to be a good OTP citizen, you do ideally want to make your long running processes into gen_server's and gen_fsm's, sometimes you have to look beyond the standard issue rule book and consider why the rules exist.

What if, for example, your supervisor starts your gen_server, and your gen_server spawns another process (lets call it the active_poll process), and they link to each other so that they have shared fate (if one dies the other dies). The active_poll process is now indirectly supervised by the supervisor that spawned the gen_server, because if it dies, so will the gen_server, and they will both get restarted. The only problem you really have to solve now is code upgrade, but this is not too difficult - your gen_server gets a `code_change` callback call when the code is to be upgraded, and it could simply send a message to the active_poll process, which can make an appropriate fully qualified function call, and bingo, it's running the new code.

If this doesn't suit you for some reason and/or you MUST use gen_server/gen_fsm/similar directly...

I'm not sure that writing a 'special process' really gives you very much. If you wrote a special process correctly, such that it is in theory compliant to OTP design principals, it could still be ineffective in practice if it blocks or busy waits in a loop somewhere, and doesn't invoke `sys` when it should, so you really have at most a small optimisation over using gen_server/gen_fsm with a zero timeout (or by having an async message handler which does the polling and sends a message to self to trigger the next poll).

If what ever you are doing to actively poll can block (such as a blocking socket read for example), this is really big trouble, as gen_server, gen_fsm or a special process will all be stopped from fullfilling their usual obligations (which they would usually be able to either because the callback in the case of gen_server/gen_fsm returns, or because `receive` is called and the `sys` module invoked explicitly in the case of a special process).

If what you are doing to actively poll is non blocking though, you can do it, but if you poll without any delay then it effectively becomes a busy wait (it's not quite because the loop will include a receive call somewhere, which means the process will yield, giving the scheduler voluntary opportunity to run other processes, but it's not far off, and it will still be a relative CPU hog). If you can have a 1ms delay between each poll that makes a world of difference vs polling as rapidly as you can. It's not ideal, but if you MUST, it'll work. So use a timeout (as big as you can without it becoming a problem), or have an async message handler which does the polling and sends a message to self to trigger the next poll.